# Read Preferred Network Type Setting

Tags: android, android-settings

I am trying to read the `Preferred network type` setting from the device. But nowhere android API's are available.

Use case: 
Trying to read the Preferred network type and connected network type so that if the device has LTE enabled and the user is forcefully switched back to the lower network(3G,2G); then there should be a notification sent to the user.

I have checked the system setting code, But it's deprecated.

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.System.NETWORK_PREFERENCE);
```

Is there any alternate way to read the system secured settings(By reflection?).
And Also is it possible to write back the setting with the user permission?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: any news about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right code is:

```
Settings.Global.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.NETWORK_PREFERENCE)
```